# Capture stdout from exec.Command line by line and also pipe to os.Stdout

Tags: go, channel

Can anyone help ?

I have an application I am running via exec.CommandContext (so I can cancel it via ctx). it would normally not stop unless it errors out.

I currently have it relaying its output to os.stdOut which is working great. But I also want to get each line via a channel - the idea behind this is I will look for a regular expression on the line and if its true then I will set an internal state of "ERROR" for example.

Although I can't get it to work, I tried NewSscanner. Here is my code.

As I say, it does output to os.StdOut which is great but I would like to receive each line as it happens in my channel I setup.

Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance.

```
func (d *Daemon) Start() {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    d.cancel = cancel

    go func() {
        args := "-x f -a 1"
        cmd := exec.CommandContext(ctx, "mydaemon", strings.Split(args, " ")...)

        var stdoutBuf, stderrBuf bytes.Buffer

        cmd.Stdout = io.MultiWriter(os.Stdout, &stdoutBuf)
        cmd.Stderr = io.MultiWriter(os.Stderr, &stderrBuf)

        lines := make(chan string)

        go func() {
            scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
            for scanner.Scan() {
                fmt.Println("I am reading a line!")
                lines <- scanner.Text()
            }
        }()

        err := cmd.Start()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        select {
        case outputx := <-lines:
            // I will do somethign with this!
            fmt.Println("Hello!!", outputx)

        case <-ctx.Done():
            log.Println("I am done!, probably cancelled!")
        }
    }()
}
```

Also tried using this

```
        go func() {
            scanner := bufio.NewScanner(&stdoutBuf)
            for scanner.Scan() {
                fmt.Println("I am reading a line!")
                lines <- scanner.Text()
            }
        }()
```

Even with that, the "I am reading a line" never gets out, I also debugged it and it neve enters the "for scanner.."

Also tried scanning on `&stderrBuf`, same, nothing enters.

Comment: You’re scanning on os.Stdin not stdout buf

Comment: Thanks, yes I also thought that but I tried it previously and it didn't work. Just tried it again.

Comment: Updated main question to include that.

Comment: Two differnt people suggested it @IanGregson, and almost just wrote the same thing.  Time to put minimal, executable reproduction of the problem into the question so we can back up our answers with better info.

Comment: (1)  The command output goes to `stdoutBuf`, not `os.Stdin`.  (2) The version of the program that reads from `stdoutBuf` has a data race on the buffer.  Fix by using a pipe instead of a buffer.  (3) You probably want a loop around the select statement.

Comment: Go figure :-) Something weird!,  so I changed the cmd to "cmd := exec.CommandContext(ctx, "ping", "127.0.0.1")" - and everything works...

So it appears its to do with my command then I am running. Maybe it detects that I am not running it a TTY or something.

Comment: I think that may not address an overall issue, which is that scanner.Scan() returns false if there is nothing to read in the reader. Depending on how the goroutines are scheduled (whether the scanner goroutine runs before or after there is output from the command) and how often the command produces output, you might miss the command output. See @CeriseLimón's comment about using a pipe. Also, the note about the for loop around select.

Comment: @IanGregson I just added an answer that addresses the points in Cerise's comment and my comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69958845/3309046. It also contains a sample main to test the normal exit and the Context-cancelation exit scenarios. I've added explanations for why it is free of races, deadlocks, and  goroutine leaks. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cmd.Start()` does not wait for the command to finish. Also, `cmd.Wait()` needs to be called to be informed about the end of the process.

```
reader, writer := io.Pipe()

cmdCtx, cmdDone := context.WithCancel(context.Background())

scannerStopped := make(chan struct{})
go func() {
    defer close(scannerStopped)

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(reader)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        fmt.Println(scanner.Text())
    }
}()

cmd := exec.Command("ls")
cmd.Stdout = writer
_ = cmd.Start()
go func() {
    _ = cmd.Wait()
    cmdDone()
    writer.Close()
}()
<-cmdCtx.Done()

<-scannerStopped
```

`scannerStopped` is added to demonstrate that the scanner goroutine stops now.

```
reader, writer := io.Pipe()

scannerStopped := make(chan struct{})
go func() {
    defer close(scannerStopped)

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(reader)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        fmt.Println(scanner.Text())
    }
}()

cmd := exec.Command("ls")
cmd.Stdout = writer
_ = cmd.Run()

go func() {
    _ = cmd.Wait()
    writer.Close()
}()

<-scannerStopped
```

And handle the lines as it helps.

Note: wrote this in a bit of hurry. Let me know if anything is unclear or not correct.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I didnt make those changes yet, my previous code was put together quick just to test.

Something weird!,  so I ONLY changed the cmd to "cmd := exec.CommandContext(ctx, "ping", "127.0.0.1")" - and everything works...

So it appears its to do with my command then I am running. Maybe it detects that I am not running it a TTY or something.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Don't know what went on, I used the io.Pipe and it started working.

Thanks everyone for their help

Comment: In the second example, should `cmd.Run()` be `cmd.Start()`? I see the message `Wait was already called` when running it and handling the `cmd.Wait()` error.

Answer (score 2):

For a correct program using concurrency and goroutines, we should try to show there are no data races, the program can't deadlock, and goroutines don't leak. Let's try to achieve this.

### Full code

**Playground:** https://play.golang.org/p/Xv1hJXYQoZq. I recommend copying and running locally, because the playground doesn't stream output afaik and it has timeouts.

Note that I've changed the test command to `% find /usr/local`, a typically long-running command (>3 seconds) with plenty of output lines, since it is better suited for the scenarios we should test.

### Walkthrough

Let's look at the `Daemon.Start` method. At the start, it is mostly the same. Most noticeably, though, the new code doesn't have a goroutine around a large part of the method. Even without this, the `Daemon.Start` method remains non-blocking and will return "immediately".

---

The first noteworthy fix is these updated lines.

```
    outR, outW := io.Pipe()
    cmd.Stdout = io.MultiWriter(outW, os.Stdout)
```

Instead of constructing a bytes.Buffer variable, we call [`io.Pipe`](https://pkg.go.dev/io#Pipe). If we didn't make this change and stuck with a bytes.Buffer, then `scanner.Scan()` will return false as soon as there is no more data to read. This can happen if the command writes to stdout only occasionally (even a millisecond apart, for this matter). After `scanner.Scan()` returns false, the goroutine exits and we miss processing future output.

Instead, by using the read end of `io.Pipe`, `scanner.Scan()` will wait for input from the pipe's read end until the pipe's write end is closed.

This fixes the race issue between the scanner and the command output.

---

Next, we construct two closely-related goroutines: the first to consume from `<-lines`, and the second to produce into `lines<-`.

```
    go func() {
        for line := range lines {
            fmt.Println("output line from channel:", line)
            ...
        }
    }()
```

```
    go func() {
        defer close(lines)
        scanner := bufio.NewScanner(outR)
        for scanner.Scan() {
            lines <- scanner.Text()
        }
        ...
    }()
```

The consumer goroutine will exit when the `lines` channel is closed, as the closing of the channel would naturally cause the range loop to terminate; the producer goroutine closes `lines` upon exit.

The producer goroutine will exit when `scanner.Scan()` returns false, which happens when the write end of the `io.Pipe` is closed. This closing happens in upcoming code.

Note from the two paragraphs above that the two goroutines are guaranteed to exit (i.e. will not leak).

---

Next, we start the command. Standard stuff, it's a non-blocking call, and it returns immediately.

```
// Start the command.
if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

---

Moving on to the final piece of code in `Daemon.Start`. This goroutine waits for the command to exit via `cmd.Wait()`. Handling this is important because the command may for reasons other than Context cancellation.

Particularly, we want to close the write end of the `io.Pipe` (which, in turn, closes the output lines producer goroutine as mentioned earlier).

```
    go func() {
        err := cmd.Wait()
        fmt.Println("command exited; error is:", err)
        outW.Close()
        ...
    }()
```

As a side note, by waiting on `cmd.Wait()`, we don't have to separately wait on `ctx.Done()`. Waiting on `cmd.Wait()` handles both exits caused by natural reasons (command successfully finished, command ran into internal error etc.) and exits caused by Context-cancelation.

This goroutine, too, is guaranteed to exit. It will exit when `cmd.Wait()` returns. This can happen either because the command   exited normally with success; exited with failure due to a command error; or exited with failure due to Context cancelation.

---

That's it! We should have no data races, no deadlocks, and no leaked goroutines.

The lines elided ("`...`") in the snippets above are geared towards the `Done()`, `CmdErr()`, and `Cancel()` methods of the Daemon type. These methods are fairly well-documented in the code, so these elided lines are hopefully self-explanatory.

Besides that, look for the `TODO` comments for error handling you may want to do based on your needs!

### Test it!

Use this driver program to test the code.

```
func main() {
    var d Daemon
    d.Start()

    // Enable this code to test Context cancellation:
    // time.AfterFunc(100*time.Millisecond, d.Cancel)

    <-d.Done()
    fmt.Println("d.CmdErr():", d.CmdErr())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to scan `stdoutBuf` instead of `os.Stdin`:

```
scanner := bufio.NewScanner(&stdoutBuf)
```

Comment: Thanks yes, I  have also tried it, my main question has been updated with the result.

Answer (score 0):

The command is terminated when the context canceled.  If  it's OK to read all output from the command until the command is terminated, then use this code:

```
func (d *Daemon) Start() {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    d.cancel = cancel

    args := "-x f -a 1"
    cmd := exec.CommandContext(ctx, "mydaemon", strings.Split(args, " ")...)
    stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    err = cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    go func() {
        defer cmd.Wait()
        scanner := bufio.NewScanner(stdout)
        for scanner.Scan() {
            s := scanner.Text()
            fmt.Println(s) // echo to stdout
            // Do something with s
        }
    }()
}
```

The command is terminated when the context is canceled.
Read on `stdout` returns io.EOF when the command is terminated. The goroutine breaks out of the scan loop when `stdout` returns an error.